# Exclude null regex groups

Tags: java, regex

Given the following line, I would like to extract some values using Pattern class in Java:

```
user1@machine1:command#user2@machine2:command....
```

Two commands are extracted:

- one to be executed on machine1 using user1
- one to be executed on machine2 using user2

If I use the following regex

```
"([^@]+)@([^:]+):([^#]+)(?:#([^@]+)@([^:]+):([^#]+))*"
```

the elements in group 1, 4, 7, ... are users

the elements in group 2, 5, 8, ... are machines

the elements in group 3, 6, 9, ... are commands

The only problem is that for only one command, the matcher detects null groups for 4, 5, 6.

Is there any Regex option for not receiving null values, for that particular situation?

Comment: There is no way to disable returning null matches (there is no branch reset in Java ICU regex), so you can only perform the null check as Mena suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using one regex for finding *all* the users, groups, and commands at once, I'd suggest splitting the process in two: First, find blocks of `user@group:command`, then identify the parts in that block. This way it will work for any number of blocks.

First, trim down your regex to match just one "block":

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^@]+)@([^:]+):([^#]+)");
String input = "user1@machine1:command1#user2@machine2:command2#user3@machine3:command3";
```

Then, either, use `String.split("#")` to split the blocks and use the regex to `match` that block:

```
for (String block : input.split("#")) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(block);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.groupCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(m.group(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Or just repeatedly `find` more matches in the original string:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.groupCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: As the first user who gave me the most appropriate answer in the comments, you deserve the Answer tick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check?

```
if (myMatcher.find()) {
    if (myMatcher.group(4) == null) {
        // TODO
    }
    // etc
```

Comment: Such checks make the code unreadable. I should use them as the last resort

Comment: I don't agree they make the code unreadable. Maybe just a little cluttered. Nothing that can't be fixed by good documentation in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bigger problem when there are 3 or more commands.  You should probably just `.split("#")` the string first, and then deal with each one individually.

Comment: Good idea. This should simplify the Regex and the code dealing with conversion. Thank you